# How to get the "General" info "required" from an Access column (Access 2003) with C#?

Tags: c#, ms-access

Before I do an update to an Access database table I want to know if every column that is required is filled in.

So I need to know if a column is required yes or no.

In the design table mode in Access, I see in the "General" tab the required info.

But how can I retrieve this information with C# code? So I'm not looking for the "AllowDBNull" boolean, but for the parameter "required" in the "General" tab.

I'm using Visual Studio 2005 and Access 2003.

Comment: It is the same thing, "Required" is non-programmer speak.  Required == !AllowDBNull.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a code here which does other things as well. I retrieve the column information by using schema tables:

```
using (DataTable dtColumns = cnn.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Columns, restrictions)) {
    string AutoNumberColumn = RetrieveAutoNumberColumn(cnn, tableSchema);
    foreach (DataRow row in dtColumns.Rows) {
        var col = new TableColumn();
        col.ColumnName = (string)row["COLUMN_NAME"];
        col.ColumnNameForMapping = prepareColumnNameForMapping(col.ColumnName);
        col.ColumnAllowsDBNull = (bool)row["IS_NULLABLE"]; // <=============
        col.ColumnIsIdentity = col.ColumnName == AutoNumberColumn;
        DbColumnFlags flags = (DbColumnFlags)(long)row["COLUMN_FLAGS"];
        col.ColumnIsReadOnly = col.ColumnIsIdentity || (flags & (DbColumnFlags.Write | DbColumnFlags.WriteUnknown)) == DbColumnFlags.None;
        if (row["CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH"] != DBNull.Value) {
            col.ColumnMaxLength = (int)(long)row["CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH"];
        }
        col.ColumnDbType = GetColumnDbType((int)row["DATA_TYPE"]);
        col.ColumnOrdinalPosition = (int)(long)row["ORDINAL_POSITION"];
        GetColumnDefaultValue(row, col);

        tableSchema.ColumnSchema.Add(col);
    }
}
```

Use this for the restrictions parameter:

```
string[] restrictions = new string[] { null, null, tableName };
```

Note: Some of the types and methods I used in this example are my own and are defined elsewhere, so this code will not works if you do not adapt it to your needs.

---

If you have a DataSet, you can also retrieve the info from the System.Data.DataColumn.AllowDBNull property (not tested).

Answer (score 0):

Consider creating a query showing the rows with required columns set to null values.  Then, from your calling routine in C#, you can just open the query.